# Handling Enterprise base Routing in Angular 2 Application

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am creating an Enterprise level application in angular 2. I want to create a feature module with their own routing. So every feature module contains multiple component and routing. At high level, it looks like main module with main routing and each feature module has its own component routing. Is is possible and how can i code it.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Comment: According to the document , the all route goes in to the routing file with their children but i want to take child route in other file with feature modules. Because as code base increase it will be hard to control routes ans second things is separate concern.

Comment: If you search for `forChild()` you'll find an example how to add routes to feature modules.